# How to add vast tag to fluid player?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, vast

```html
[fluid-player-extended
    layout="funky"
    auto-play="autoPlay"
    logo="https://www.fluidplayer.com/images/yourlogo.png"
    logo-position="top right"
    logo-opacity=".8"
    ad-text="adText"
    ad-cta-text="adCTAText"
    html-on-pause-block-width="100"
    html-on-pause-block-height="100"
    responsive="responsive"]

    [fluid-player-multi-res-video]
        [
            {"label": "720", "url": "http://cdn.fluidplayer.com/current/examples/video.mp4"},
            {"label": "360", "url": "http://cdn.fluidplayer.com/current/examples/video360.mp4"}
        ]
    [/fluid-player-multi-res-video]

    [fluid-player-html-block]
        <div>
            <img src="https://www.fluidplayer.com/images/yourbanner.png" />
        </div>
    [/fluid-player-html-block]

[/fluid-player-extended]
```

---

How can someone implement a vast tag url to this code.
Example url looks like - https://syndication.exdynsrv.com/splash.php?idzone=2916384